# Cannot see my second collectionView on viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So I have my program where I have two collection views on the same ViewController. However when I run the app I can only see one. I have set the constraints on the image the same way on both.

the arrays productsImages and StoresImages are names of images I have in my assets folder. Firthermore pillImage and compStoreImage I have as outlet on my ColectionViewCell files.

HomeViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var productCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var storesCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(collectionView == storesCollectionView) {
                return storesImages.count
            }
            return productsImages.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = productCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "productsCell", for: indexPath) as! productCollectionViewCell
        
        cell.pillImage.image = UIImage(named: productsImages[indexPath.row])
        
        if(collectionView == storesCollectionView) {
            let cell2 = storesCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "storesCell", for: indexPath) as! StoreCollectionViewCell
            cell2.compstoreImage.image = UIImage(named: storesImages[indexPath.row])
            
            return cell2
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    
    var productsImages:[String] = ["pillImage", "pillyImage", "pillsImage"]
    var storesImages:[String] = ["compstoreImage", "compeImage", "compeStore"]

    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

StoreCollectionViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class StoreCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var compstoreImage: UIImageView!
    
   
    
}
```

productCollectionViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class productCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var pillImage: UIImageView!
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW9g1.png)

Comment: In your `cellForItemAt` method, if(collectionView == productCollectionView) {
 let cell = ...
} else {
 let cell2 = ...
}

Comment: Are you sure you set HomeViewController as the delegate and dataSource for both collections view??

Comment: Thanks Alganadi! I forgot to do that!